# Can you recommend a good MySQL stored procedure debugger?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, debugging

Can you recommend a good MySQL stored procedure debugger?
**Extra points if it is open source, and works in linux :)**

Comment: is this one of the reasons why I shouldn't use them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither open source (**but freeware**) nor works in linux, but [Toad® for MySQL](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/) should be able to assist you in debugging stored procedures on a Windows client.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [SQLYog MySQL editor](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_list.php) and it has some nice features. Unfortunately it does not really meet your criteria. There is a community edition though, so its half way there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if [this](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) would meet your requirement but it's the only thing that comes to mind.

---

Edit: [This](http://mysql-debugger.safe-install.com/) may also be helpful but it doesn't quite meet either the free or available on Linux test.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following MySQL debugger that supports breakpoints, a call stack, a variables evaluation, watches of any routines (procedures, function and even triggers)
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html.

But, unfortunately, it runs only on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The best mysql debugger is in dbForge Studio for MySQL! (imho)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Illatis StepIn, debug MySQL stored procedures in Windows and Linux. See this page: http://www.illatis.com/downloads/downloads.php.

Cheers